# Django Template Not Rendered by Browser

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to set up django view for my web application which redirects the page once a file upload is complete, and the status bar showing the upload progress reaches 100%.  I have looked around online and attempted to do this in several ways but nothing seems to be working.  When I use

```
render(request, 'template_name')
```

The application simply returns the plain text of 'template_name' to the console rather than rendering it in the browser window.  The original page of the loading bar stays in place after this plain text is returned.

My view looks like the following

```
def barUpdate(request):
    importid = request.GET.get('impid')
    response_data = {}
    import_status_dict = get_import_status(importid)
    status_id = import_status_dict['returnval']
    import_status_info = import_status_dict['data_row']
    import_status_info = import_status_info[0]
    total_rows = import_status_info['total_data_rows']
    rows_analyzed = import_status_info['number_of_rows_analyised']



    if status_id != 2:
        if (rows_analyzed != None and total_rows != None):

            percent_complete = int((float(rows_analyzed)/total_rows)*100) 
            response_data['value'] = percent_complete

        if 'percent_complete' in locals():
            if response_data['value'] >= 100:
                #return render(request,'statustool/completed.html',{'importid':importid,'username':username,'failedparameters':new_failed_param_group,'failedsources':failed_sources,'failedparametergroups':failed_parameters_group,'failedsitegroups':failed_sites_group,'sources':get_sources(), 'failedunits':failed_units})
                    #Right here I would like to render a new template in my browser, although this is just a dummy template I created for testing
                return render(request,'statustool/test.html')
            response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
            return response
        else: 
            response_data['value'] = 0
            response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
            return response
```

My dummy template is the following which contains no variables to be passed in from the view

```
<html>
<head>
    test
</head>
<body>
<h1>Finished with data insert!</h1>
</body>



</html>
```

Is there something I am missing?

If it helps, the current page with the status bar looks like the following and uses a javascript function called status to make GET requests every second to find the upload status for the status bar

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>CACW: Status - Processing</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- Le styles -->
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/boostrap-responsive.css" rel="stylsheet">
    <style>
        body,html{
            padding-top: 30px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
        }
        .container{
            min-height:100%;
        }
        .footer{
            height:40px;
            margin-top:-25px;
        }
        .barcontainer{
          width: 100px;
          color: blue;
        }

         progress {  
            background-color: whiteSmoke;
            border-radius: 2px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;

            width: 250px;
            height: 20px;

            position: relative;
            display: block;
        }  
        </style>


        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/d3examples.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var importNum = {{importid}}


          function status(){
            var barProgress = window.setInterval("getProgress(importNum);", 1000);
          }


          var url=api_server_address+"import/status/update/";
          var getProgress =  function(importid) {
              $.ajax({
              url: "https://cacw.luc.edu/status/update/",
              data: { impid: importid },
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json"
              })
                .done(function(data){
                $('#progressBar').val(data['value']);
                console.log(data);
            });
          }

        </script>    

</head>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="brand" href="#">CACW</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="/login/authed/userhome/">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#wiki">Wiki</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
             <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="/logout">Logout</a>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



<body onload="status({{importid}});">
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
         <p><h2>Import {{ importid }} Status.</h2></p>
     {{percent_complete}}


      <progress id="progressBar" value={{status}} max="100"></progress>


    </div>
</div>



    <div class="footer">
        <div class="navbar-fixed-bottom">
            <hr>
            <div class = "container" style="text-align: center">

                <p> <a href = " "> Help </a>  - <a href = " "> Information </a>- <a href = " "> Contact </a>- <a href = " ">  Wiki </a> <p>
                <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/luc_logo.jpg"></img>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the page that is calling this? Or the relevant Javascript? Chances are that is what you need to change.

Comment: I added the html for the page calling this with the javascript function. I'm not sure if that function has something to do with the issue since it updates the status bar every second, and once it hits 100 percent, it continues the GET requests which just returns the plain text every second rather than the upload progress.

Comment: Is your link really to `css/boostrap-responsive.css` or perhaps `css/bootstrap-responsive.css`? Leaving out the first `t` is a common typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are just getting the data in an AJAX call, this will never update your page (from the server side). What you can do is add a flag/object/parameter to your servers response to indicate when the upload is done, then on the client side, redirect to that location when the upload is finished.

Server side:

```
# code shortened a bit... continues from after line defining percent complete
response_data['value'] = percent_complete if 'percent_complete' in locals() else 0
response_data['done'] = response_data['value'] >= 100

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

Client Side:

```js
var getProgress =  function(importid) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://cacw.luc.edu/status/update/",
        data: { impid: importid },
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        if(data['done']) {
            // I forget if this is how to do a redirect but it's where you put it
            location.href('whatever/your/url/is');
        } else {
            $('#progressBar').val(data['value']);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
  }
```